# File::Find is failing in subdirectories

Tags: perl

I have a sub that find .vcf files in a sub-directories of the main directory, using `File::Find::name` that was working great in one environment but is not working on another machine(both run red hat linux) . It stillfinds .vcf files if it's in the main directory but fails to find in a sub-directory.
Could someone please help to troubleshoot?

Here is an example of a file it fails to find (broken over lines for readability):

```
/home/yeliiley/mdl3/results/SN1-376-OFA_TL127445_CHIP1_052318_BSN/
  MD-18-6297_BG_v1_ac9023be-8db4-440b-9095/Variants/
  MD-18-6297_BG_v1_MD-18-6297_BG_RNA_v1/
  MD-18-6297_BG_v1_MD-18-6297_BG_RNA_v1_Non-Filtered_2018-05-24_040909.vcf
```

however, if the file is in `$main_dir` it finds it.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use File::Find;

my $main_dir = "/home/yeliiley/mdl3/results/SN1-376-OFA_TL127445_CHIP1_052318_BSN";
my $location=$main_dir;

sub find_vcf {
    my $F = $File::Find::name;

    if ($F =~ /vcf$/ ) {
        print "here is the vcf.$F\n";

        $F =~ m|([^/]+).vcf$| or die "Can't extract Sample ID";
        my $sample_id = $1; print "the short vcf name is: $sample_id\n";

    }else {
        print "Did not find any vcf files $F\n";
    }
}

find({ wanted => \&find_vcf, no_chdir=>1}, $location);
```

Comment: Not your specific issue, but did you notice that your regex fails to escape a dot?  `m|([^/]+).vcf$|` matches a.vcf, but also aavcf, abvcf, a-vcf, etc.

Comment: Is this "_other machine_" Linux as well (you use `/` for the directory separator)?  Are you trying to extract the base `name` from `/path/to/dir/name.vcf`?

Comment: Can you post an example of a filename it "_fails to find_", with full path?

Comment: Note: you don't need an `if` to detect that `vcf` is there and then another regex to extract name, and you don't need to use `$1`. Instead: `if (my ($n) = $F =~ m{...}) {...}`

Comment: Works for me on my PC.  Are you sure the VCF files exist on other workstation?  Can you print out the file name that doesn't match VCF, like `else { print "$F is not a VCF file\n"; }`?  It might help you to see what the script is actually looking at.

Comment: @jimtut. It doesn't seem to be looking in sub-folders but only at files in the  main directory.

Comment: Data is not on the machine the code is running, but is on a mounted drive (mdl3) a different Linux machine.

Comment: Thank you for the update. (I formatted what you added as it was completely unreadable. Please, can you at least attempt to format such things? It appears awkward that you ask folks for help and then just dump a line like that.)

Comment: You are asking `File::Find` to search `SN1-376-OFA_TL127445_CHIP1_052318_BSN` but the "missing" file is under `SN1-376-OFA_TL127445_CHIP1_052318_BS`. Are there actually any `.vcf` files in subdirectories of the place you're actually searching?

Comment: @zdim: I thought you were responding to my comment, asking if the directories really didn't match. You have a question mark there!

Comment: The same code work perfectly on Linux server but not a particular machine I now trying to run the code.  This issue is probably related to how the machine was built.  I don't know what to do.

Comment: @Borodin Ah, right!  It was for the OP ... :)  Removing that, since your comment is perfect ..

Comment: @user: We're not going to get anywhere if you just manually edit your question to remove discrepancies. You need to *copy and paste* information for it to mean anything.

Comment: @user Um, no, what you show can't "_work perfectly_" -- see @Borodin's comment. Your `$main_dir` has `..BSN/` in name while the file you show has `...BS/`.  Unless it's a typo in posting?

Comment: @user: *"The same code work perfectly on Linux server"* I'm not interested in where you think it worked. The most likely explanation here is that you have made a mistake, and I want to see a file path that you think your program has missed that matches what is in the code. **Don't just type one in—copy and paste it from your console.**

Comment: @user Please _please_ be careful with your posts.  When we see a question we have no clue about your problem and every little piece matters.  Incorrect information and back-and-forths in fixing things are devastating for my desire to spend time this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "follow => 1" to your find() call, i.e.

```
find({ wanted => \&find_vcf , no_chdir => 1, follow => 1}, $location);
```

Comment: Any idea why this is required for the Op on one workstation?  It wasn't required for his/her other workstation, and wasn't required when I setup a test case for this.

Comment: @jimtut  Maybe because some of the directories are symlinks on that other computer?